# Boto3 S3 - Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

everyone.

Currently we have a problem with boto3 in Python. We are trying to get object in AWS S3:

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read()
```

But in some cases AWS returns an error: "***Connection was  closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL***"

This error happens completely randomly, there is no common pattern for it to fail, is an intermittent error. In many cases it manages to read the file correctly, but in other cases the error is displayed.

This happens inside Elastic Beanstalk on AWS, it is not a local test. I clarify this, because in some similar forums they mention that it may be antivirus, firewall or VPN issue and we are not using any of these inside AWS.

We initially we tried to add the region_name in the code, but it did not work.

Here logs from boto3 when raise error:

```
File "/opt/python/current/app/customscripts/scripts/backend_940.py", line 67, in read 
lines = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_url.bucket, Key=s3_url.key)['Body'].read().decode()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 706, in _make_api_call
operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 725, in _make_request
return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 106, in make_request
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: What kind of connectivity do you have to S3?

Comment: We use local connectivity with a VPC-endpoint to s3

Comment: Can you enable debugging in boto3 and paste the log during error occurs?

Comment: I added logs from boto in answer @MohanShanmugam

Comment: If the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance and it is accessing data on Amazon S3 (preferably in the same region), then there should be no connectivity issues. How big is the file? An alternative would be to download the file first, then read it locally.

Comment: The size of the files is varied, it is not an alternative to download, because it receives all day long many files, this could fill the disk. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: You could save the file, read it, then delete it. At least try this to see if it resolves the problem. It would separate the "download" portion from the "read" portion and help you identify what is causing the problem.